# Loop components without array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, jsx

I have a render in my component that renders out many components and i want it to repeat some of them. The problem I have is when I create an HTML render the variable is not being processed and it is displaying as text.

The actual code contains many more componentsbut I have simplified it

MY code

```
export default function(props) {
  const bookData = props.bookData;
  const pageStart = props.pageStart;
  // Create Diary HTML
  const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
    let html = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++) {
      let singleLoop = `<DiaryByDay loop={${i}} />`;
      html = html + '  ' + singleLoop;
    }
    return html;
  };

const dayByDayPages = myLoop(1, 3);
const dayByDayReturn = <Fragment>  {dayByDayPages}  </Fragment>
console.log(dayByDayReturn)


  return (
    dayByDayReturn
  );
}
```

This is what it looks like when I run my code
[image]

Comment: Could you please make a reproducible example to show what you are actually getting?

Comment: That's normal, you should return an array not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JSX element as return type

```
export default function(props) {
  const bookData = props.bookData;
  const pageStart = props.pageStart;
  // Create Diary HTML
  const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
    return [...new Array(loopNumber)].map(i => <DiaryByDay loop={i} />);
  };

  const dayByDayPages = myLoop(1, 3);
  const dayByDayReturn = <Fragment> {dayByDayPages} </Fragment>;
  console.log(dayByDayReturn);
  return dayByDayReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The React is printing the component as string because you are saving component as string.

You could store the component in array and then render it.

Try this.

```
export default function(props) {
    const bookData = props.bookData;
    const pageStart = props.pageStart;
    // Create Diary HTML
    const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
      let html = [];
     for (let i = loopNumber; i < pageStart; i++) {
        let singleLoop = <DiaryByDay loop={${i}} />;
        html.push(singleLoop);
      }
      return html;
    };
  const dayByDayPages = myLoop(1, 3);
  const dayByDayReturn = <Fragment> {dayByDayPages}  </Fragment>


    return (
      dayByDayReturn
    );
  }
```

Codesandbox Example:

[image: Edit Loop components without array]

Comment: THanks - but  I tried it and got "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `dayByDayReturn' before initialization"

Comment: It is still being seen as a text string. The compnent is just rendering "<DiaryByDay loop={0} />" as text on the page

Comment: I have updated the code and added a codeSandbox example too.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending strings, not React elements. You need to append to an array:

```
export default function(props) {
  const bookData = props.bookData;
  const pageStart = props.pageStart;
  // Create Diary HTML
  const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
    const elements = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++) {
      elements.push(<DiaryByDay loop={i} key={i} />);
    }
    return elements;
  };

  const dayByDayPages = myLoop(3, 3);
  const dayByDayReturn = <> {dayByDayPages} </>;

  return dayByDayReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function so that it returns an array:

```
 const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
    let html = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++) {
      let singleLoop = <DiaryByDay loop={i} />;
      html.push(singleLoop);
    }
    return html;
  };
```

If you return a huge string obviously it'll try to display the string.

And you should also add a key prop to each DiaryByDay component. Using index value might not be a good idea for that because if you later delete some elements in your array the indexes change.

So 
`let singleLoop = <DiaryByDay loop={i} />;`

should be

`let singleLoop = <DiaryByDay key={ ...something unique for each element} loop={i} />;`

Answer (score 1):

You must return an array of elements:

```
const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
  return [...Array(loopNumber).keys()].map(v => <DiaryByDay key={v} loop={v} />);
};
```

Or

```
const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
    const html = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++) {
      html.push(<DiaryByDay key={i} loop={i} />);
    }
    return html;
  };
```

**Demo**:

```js
const Fragment = React.Fragment;

function DiaryByDay(props) {
  return <div>DiaryByDay {props.loop}</div>
}

function App(props) {
  //const bookData = props.bookData;
  //const pageStart = props.pageStart;
  // Create Diary HTML
  const myLoop = (loopNumber, pageStart) => {
    return [...Array(loopNumber).keys()].map(v => <DiaryByDay key={v} loop={v} />);
  };

const dayByDayPages = myLoop(4, 3);
const dayByDayReturn = <Fragment>  {dayByDayPages}  </Fragment>
//console.log(dayByDayReturn)


  return (
    dayByDayReturn
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```